# sending massive amounts of TCP data

Tags: c#, tcp

So im working with C#, and i have to send lots and lots of data every time a client makes an initial connection.. I would prefer to have some way to track the progress of the message, and one way i thought to do that would be to split my large amount of data into 500 or more smaller portions, and send them individually. Would that be an acceptable practice? or is it better to send one gigantic message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do when sending large amounts of data is send it in 100 pieces each being more than 50kb and then update a progress bar by whatever the current percentage is.  I do it by serializing the file to a byte[] and then in a while loop, send then `Application.DoEvents()` to update the UI.

I'm sure you could use Async background workers as well and then have the Update event increment the progress bar.

I would say, if you can split it up, do it. Because if there is an interruption in the connection you can always restart etc.  That's why bittorrent and the ilk divide file into chunks.

Just make sure that you have good checksums and error detection.  The more pieces you split, the more pieces you have to keep track of.

Comment: Ill accept yours for the last half of it - the beginning is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you :)  the first part of the message was in reply to you saying "I would prefer to have some way to track the progress of the message..."  I was explaining how you could track the progress using progress bars.  Semi irrelevant maybe, but not totally irrelevant

Comment: Why in the world would you call `Application.DoEvents` instead of doing the download on a background thread?

Comment: because you can. that's why I suggested both methods. maybe he'll want to port the code to a mobile device or has a thread limitation.

Comment: You said that you do it by calling `Application.DoEvents`. I honestly wouldn't take advice from anyone who suggests they do that in their own projects. The possibility of re-entrancy and other nasty bugs more than overwhelm any "convenience" that it may provide. Anyone who has been around long enough to know how to use it correctly also knows why they shouldn't ever use it in the first place.